# I have hosted my webiste on Github but i am facing this issue "The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file."

Tags: git, github, hosting

https://baboo523.github.io/My-Portfolio/

I have hosted my website on Github but I am facing this issue "The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file." link is given above

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that github-pages looks for `index.html`, which does not exist in your branch, I have opened a pull request to fix it, please have a look and test it:

https://github.com/Baboo523/My-Portfolio/pull/1

Note that I made the PR against your gh-pages branch (not master)